# Syntax changes when migrating Gulp 3.x to 4.0

Tags: gulp

this is for a practice project I'm working on however I'm facing compatibility issues with the latest Node version and gulp v3.9. All solutions have pointed me to upgrading to Gulp 4.0 but the syntax changed and the v3.9 file is not working.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('default', ['move-dev-config', 'move-test-config'], function() {
  return tsProject.src()
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .js.pipe(gulp.dest('built'));
});

gulp.task('move-dev-config', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./src/test-config.json', './src/dev-config.json'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('built'));
});

gulp.task('move-test-config', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./src/test/mocha.opts'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('built/test'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return tsProject.src()
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .js.pipe(gulp.dest('built'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['scripts'], function() {
  gulp.watch([
    './src/*.ts',
    './src/**/*.ts',
    './src/**/**/*.ts',
  ], ['scripts']);
});
```

This is the v3.9 gulp file I'm trying to migrate to 4.0. How would a migration to 4.0 syntax look like?

Example of a change I did that did not work (says 'move-def-config' is undefined)

```
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('move-dev-config', 'move-test-config'), function() {
  return tsProject.src()
    .pipe(tsProject())
    .js.pipe(gulp.dest('built'));
}));
```

Comment: You should show the code changes that you tried as well.

Comment: added the changes

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  You should also show those.  For one, I would move your `default` task to after any tasks that it refers to.